# Evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\int _{x-1}^{x+1}\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{\ln \left(t\right)+1}dt\:\right)$

Tags: integration, limits, continuity

> Evaluate $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\int _{x-1}^{x+1}\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{\ln \left(t\right)+1}dt\:\right)$$

I have to calculate this limit of an integral. I notice that both $x+1$ and $x-1$ have limit equal to infinity. So can I say that the upper and lower limits are the same and then the integral is zero?

Answer (score 0):

You can bound by CS using the lower limit i.e. $$\left|\int _{x-1}^{x+1}\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{\log \left(t\right)+1}{\rm d}t\right| \leq \int_{x-1}^{x+1} \frac{{\rm d}t}{\log(t)+1} \leq \frac{2}{\log(x-1)+1}\,.$$